# Why do some unrelated websites (appear to) share certificates?

Tags: certificates

If you browse to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/ you see a certificate error.

In Chrome:

> This server could not prove that it is blog.stackoverflow.com; its security certificate is from ssl4245.cloudflare.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

In Firefox:

> The certificate is only valid for the following names: ssl4245.cloudflare.com, *.redditmedia.com, redditmedia.com, trzi30ic.com, *.trzi30ic.com, reddit.com, *.kmylvwo5.com, foodpanda.com.br, *.reddit.com, *.foodpanda.com.br, kmylvwo5.com

What a bizarre list of websites! I know Reddit, and foodpanda.com.br is presumably a Brazilian site, but `trzi30ic.com` and `kmylvwo5.com` sound downright suspicious.

Why do these websites share a certificate? I can't believe Foodpanda has any relation to Reddit.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNKqg.png

Comment: To be sure, the answer is probably I don't understand certificates, rather than any fault with those websites.

Comment: I can copy this very strange behavior. I am located in Switzerland. This site, https://security.stackexchange.com,  however, has the certificate as expected.